# Modify regex for max length

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm evaluating a phone number in js with this regex:

```
/[a-z]/i.test(this.state.phone)
```

Now I need to limit its length to 30 chars.
I tried so many times but basically I know I need to specify max lenght in curly braces like this:

```
/[a-z]{30}/i.test(this.state.phone)
```

But this way the check about letters doesn't work anymore. 
I've spended too much time on it I need some help!

EDIT: to clarify I need to avoid any letter (upper or lowercase) or special char but round brackets, space, dot, minus and plus sign.
So this is ok:

> +001.333 123456

this not

> +001 333 123456v

Comment: {0,30} if im correct this should check for a length between 0 and 30

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> Now I need to limit its length to 30 chars

`/[a-z]{30}/i` will check for exact 30 characters, you need to specify minimum length as well.

```
/\d{1,30}/i
```

`{1,30}` will check for *min* `1` and *max* `30` characters.

Also, if there no other characters allowed in `this.state.phone`, then asset *start of string* `^` and *end of string* `$` as well.

```
/^(\+)?[0-9\s]{1,30}$/
```

Comment: this doesn't work since if I pass: +001 333 123456v it pass.

Comment: Can you share the validation rules for your phone number? Like what should be allowed and what should not be allowed.

Comment: added in the topic with examples.Thanks for your answer

Comment: Please check the updated regex and let me know if this works.

Comment: unfortunately passes the +001 333 123456v

Comment: Did you checked the last regex or first?

Comment: Glad it worked for you, please accept and **upvote** the answer that helped you.

Comment: hahhaa because somebody gives u a minus? Sometimes I didn't understand people...it's ok anyways!

Comment: @Black.Jack Not sure what was funny about it, upvoted answers comes up the search and hence help future users. You can un-accept the answer for all I care!